I want my Jpos Server handle Json format message through TCP/IP or Postman, i don't know how to proceed
The final objective is to be able to take a JSON message from any client, convert it into ISOMsg, and send it to a destination server able to answer ISO 8583 messages ( I use Jpos Server to simulate a core banking server).
What has been done already on my server-side using Spring-Boot:7

I create a server config file handling XML messages using an XMLChannel and XMLPackager
I have built many Mux and Many ChannelAdaptor (One Mux per Channel) (config file)
I create also a transaction manger config file
I get the Pan of the transaction and get the channel according to the Bin of the pan to route the financial transaction

Question:
I want my JPOS server to handle JSON messages, not XML ones as I'm doing now. What should I do? It seems I have to create a custom channel, what about Packager? what about the RequestListener?
Another idea, I had is to receive and parse the Json message to get the associated XML format before processing it as I'm doing already. Problem: I don't where to start creating this parser, any idea to solve my problem is well received.
Thanks in advance

Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding about how to ask a good question.

This question is more suitable for the jPOS mailing list, or the jPOS #support slack channel. See the jPOS resources page for mor resources.

You need to create a JSONPackager - there's one, on hold due to some dependencies conflicts, but you can take it as an inspiration:
https://github.com/jpos/jPOS/blob/master/jpos/src/main/java/org/jpos/iso/packager/JSONPackager.hold
